# Cannot install scikit-learn in Python 3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

I am trying to get scikit-learn to Python 3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04. When a run the command:

```
sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

I get scikit-learn loaded into Python 2.7. 
I have also tried to use:

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

but I get only scikit-learn into Python 2.7.
I am able load numpy and scipy into Python 3 using:

```
apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

but python3-sklearn does not work.

I tried also to create a p3env but it did not work:

```
sudo virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
source py3env/bin/activate
(py3env)user:~$sudo pip install scikit-learn
Requiement already up-to-date:scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: Probably your question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip

Comment: Thanks Chintan. I tried the recommendation in the link but it did not work for me. I updated my question with the virtual environment procedure but as you can see it did not work.

Comment: Did you try out the instructions from the answer by @akaIDIOT ? It tells you to install the Python 3 version of pip.

Comment: Thanks, it was the solution that worked:  install:easy_install3 pip and then use pip3.4 install scikit-learn

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 15):

I successfully installed `scikit-learn` for python3 on 14.04 using the following steps:

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-pip libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base`
- `sudo pip3 install scikit-learn`

According to the [official doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html),  make sure that ATLAS is used to provide the implementation of the BLAS and LAPACK linear algebra routines:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 \
    /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 \
    /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3
```

I can now use `scikit-learn`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, many Python packages that do not have explicit `python3` implementations in the package manager (`aka`, `python-numpy`, `python3-numpy`) are Python3 compatible and can be installed by downloading the package and running:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

In other words, the setup script from `python3`.

Many of the packages that are not immediately compatible require only a handful of common changes, for example `print/print()`, `xrange()/range()`, `range()/list(range())`, `zip()/list(zip())`.

You can probably also use the standard install process and then copy the libraries from the python2x "dist-packages" folders to the python3x "dist-packages" folders, but that is a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn python3-sklearn-lib python3-sklearn-doc
```

to install `scikit-learn` to use Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.